How to Autopopulate Contact in D365 Contact Centre Using Copilot
I am working on a process where I'd like to autopopulate a contact in the D365 Contact Centre based on the details provided by Copilot. Could you provide guidance or best practices for integrating this functionality?
Specifically, I am looking for a solution that can dynamically extract user details (e.g., name, email, phone) from Copilot and automatically map these details to the relevant fields in the Contact entity within Dynamics 365.

Any insights or examples would be greatly appreciated!
